# Button is not changing background color on click in ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-button

In a flutter app, I have a `FilledButton` in a `ListView` widget and one outside the `ListView`. Both these Buttons are identical in terms of their code, they just live inside different parents:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                FilledButton(
                    onPressed: () { },
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Colors.black;
                          }
                          return Colors.white;
                        }),
                        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Colors.white;
                          }
                          return Colors.black;
                        }),
                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                          return const ContinuousRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black));
                        }),
                        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                          return const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10);
                        })
                    ),
                    child: Text("Button Text")
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FilledButton(
              onPressed: () { },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                      return Colors.black;
                    }
                    return Colors.white;
                  }),
                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                      return Colors.white;
                    }
                    return Colors.black;
                  }),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                    return const ContinuousRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black));
                  }),
                  animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                    return const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10);
                  })
              ),
              child: Text("Button Text")
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

However, they somehow behave differently when clicked: [GIF showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRo7L.gif).

The one outside the `ListView` changes (background-)color as expected. Yet the button inside the `ListView` widget does only change its (background-)color when it is pressed for a little longer time: [GIF also showing the longer button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxyC0.gif).

I already looked for other questions regarding similar issues, yet I couldn't find any so far. Also the flutter documentation did not help me as I simply don't know where to even start looking for a possible solution. I am quite new to Flutter, so I also don't know if this is intended behaviour for `ListView` or not. In the case it is, what would be an alternative to `ListView` that renders the first button just like the second one?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with ListView. When you set physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), everything seems to be normal. I think maybe the scroll priority of ListView is higher than the click event of FilledButton, so it only changes its background color when it is pressed for a longer time.

Comment: that would also be my guess. yet, this would be very weird behaviour as the `onPressed` handler is still being called. just the `MaterialState` does not get updated as well. sadly, I also cannot find any documentation on this behaviour. do you have an idea how to work around this issue without basically building the button from scratch using a `GestureDetector` or something similar?

Comment: You can replace FilledButton with ElevatedButton; upon testing, ElevatedButton doesn't encounter this issue